# Plesk Webserver - New domain redirects to server IP rather than index.html

Tags: plesk

I'm running Plesk 12.0.18 on Ubuntu 12.04.5 and have a problem with a recently added domain.

The domain was added to plesk for a new website and has its own directory (httpdocs/goodsnap). When I visit the domain http://goodsnap.co.uk it redirects to the default domain on the server IP rather than opening the index.html file within httpdocs/goodsnap.

I can open the index file manually by going to http://goodsnap.co.uk/index.html and also get into WP by going to http://goodsnap.co.uk/wordpress

Can anyone advise how to rectify this? I have tried setting a redirect to the wordpress subdirectory by placing a .htaccess in httpdocs/goodsnap but it makes no difference.

Many Thanks
Tom

Comment: Currently, the Default Domain Page is opened in both cases, for a domain name and when requesting `index.html` directly.
Did you put web content in `httpdocs/goodsnap`? Did you set up the correct document root in `Hosting Settings`?

Comment: Thanks for your help Elvis, it was just me being stupid. I never checked it in another browser and it seems it was just something in Chrome's cache causing the issue as it's all good now I've cleared it. I should really learn to check the basics first!